# How can i publish an app from appMobi?

Tags: web-applications, publish, appmobi

I tested on the XDK and appLab, and it's great, but how can i publish this to build a webapp ?

This app is for publicity on to another app. (mini-game) to work with android and ios.

The request is Hype or html5, so i am building this in HTML5 using appMobi. Any tip will be of great help.

If i forgot some information to help you understand, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XDK to publish a web application as well as creating a native mobile application.  Once you have created the application and tested it on device, you'll click on the "Build For App Store" button.

[image: Build for app store]

Next, you'll choose from the website builds.  You can select a distribution build where you would receive a bundle that includes all the assets of the application along with a manifest of the files, or you can select a hosted build where appMobi will host your application on the web for you.

[image: Website Builds]

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. i did what you said. i tried the "distribution build as HTML5 webapp" downloaded the file and send in an web page for tests in my iPad2 http://joobyt.com/webapp/  The circle should be falling and the accelerometer should be working, as it does on appLab. Any sugestions ??

Comment: Once you have app.lab installed, please point the browser on your device to:
http://services.appmobi.com/appmobitest/amtlaunch.aspx?appname=dimension.accelerometro2&rel=3.4.0&target=QA

Comment: You need to be using it in AppLab or a built app.  The web browser does not expose the native functions implemented from AppMobi